# Regex - Anything followed by rules

Tags: regex, sed

I have a list which looks like:

```
imagetest-14f66c4664-d8ngk
image-net-kxpxc
image-deploy-787d65b646-6bhtn
```

I would like to build a regex expression that matches any String follow by
either

- a `-` followed by 5 chars  OR
- a `-` followed by 8 to 10 chars followed by `-` and 5 chars

The regex should match all:

```
imagetest-14f66c4664-d8ngk
image-net-kxpxc
image-deploy-787d65b646-6bhtn
waeve-net-xgw8m
```

Would there be a simple way to do so?

Comment: Try `sed -E 's/-([a-z0-9]{5}|[a-z0-9]{8,10}).*//'`

Comment: Thanks. The sed I built works, but I can't "translate" it into a regex.

Comment: Your question is still not that clear. Try https://ideone.com/A7iDpS, `sed -E 's/(-([a-z0-9]{5}|[a-z0-9]{8,10}))+$//'`

Comment: What could I add besides "Matching any String followed by -[5chars] or -[8 to 10chars]-[5chars]" ? Genuinely asking to make my quesiton more precise.

Comment: Based on your sample data, the `-[8 to 10 chars]` seems extraneous to your requirement All of then will be filtered, just by matching `-[5 chars]`, right? Good luck.

Comment: Ok, see [`(-[a-z0-9]{8,10})?-[0-9a-z]{5}$`](https://regex101.com/r/mQLagb/1). If you want to remove this matched text from the lines above, you need to use it as `sed -E 's/(-[a-z0-9]{8,10})?-[0-9a-z]{5}$//'`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like (see https://regexr.com/3t88e)

```
-([0-9a-f]+-)?([a-z0-9]{5})$
```

will match.

Basically:

- a dash,
- an optional group of hexadecimals followed by a dash (`([0-9a-f]+-)?`),
- a group of 5-character identifier of alphanumerics (`([a-z0-9]{5})`),
- anchored to the end of the string (`$`)

(However be aware that this will also match `image-hello`, as `hello` could be mistaken for the 5-character identifier.)

*EDIT*: To match the entire string, augment to

```
^image(?:test|-net|-deploy)-([0-9a-f]+-)?([a-z0-9]{5})$
```

so the literal "image", followed by `test`, `-net` or `-deploy`, followed by what was described above.

Comment: It's almost this!
This expression matches only the "hash" (`-14f66c4664-d8ngk`) , but not the entire String (`imagetest-14f66c4664-d8ngk`). Is there a way to do so ?

Comment: @Mornor Edited that in.

Comment: I re-edited my question to make it clearer, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

What about this: `^(image(?:test|-net|-deploy))-(.+)$`

- `^` anchors to the beginning of the line
- `(...)` surrounds a matching group
- `(?:...)` surrounds a non-matching group
- `|` provides an "*or*" allowing one of multiple options
- `.+` matches any character (`.`) one or more times (`+`)
- `$` anchors to the end of the line

This results in the following groups:

```
imagetest      14f66c4664-d8ngk
image-net      kxpxc
image-deploy   787d65b646-6bhtn
```

Have a play at Regex101 - the explanation is good too: https://regex101.com/r/0CphvX/3

Comment: Unfortunately, the expression to match could have some more string than what I have (for example also `weave-net-xgw8m`). It's more about matching a String that is followed by a hash, which is randomly composed.

Comment: Done! Thank you.